# R package leaps: Undefined Mallows Cp in results

Tags: r

I am running all possible regression models on 92 variables in the R package 'leaps', predicting one dependent variable. Each of these variables consists of 51 numerical values.

Leaps produces five model statistics (i.e., r-square, adjusted r-square, residual sum of square, Mallow's Cp, and BIC). My results show seemingly normal values for each of these statistics, except Mallow's Cp, where all values are are negative infinity. Clearly there is division by zero as some point, but I am not familiar enough with model fit statistics to know whether this is a problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just being introduced to Mallow's Cp but it sounds like you have more variables than data points. The s^2 is the MSE for the full model (has all variables). But since you have more variables than data points, the data is fit perfectly by the extraneous variables. So you should either collect more data or find a means to reduce the number of variables other than Mallow's Cp.

Cp = RSS/s^2 + N - 2*p

s^2 = MSE for the full model.

You can look at this reference here: http://www.public.iastate.edu/~mervyn/Stat401E_Spring2013/Other/mallows.pdf